# Traducción en cola de revisión de publicaciones de baja calidad para pregunta antigua

Tags: bug, traducciones

Al revisar la cola de 'Publicaciones de baja calidad' encontré una respuesta que debe ser eliminada por no ser en realidad una respuesta. La pregunta se realizó en agosto de 2016, al darle clic al botón 'Eliminación recomendada' el modal que aparece contiene una cadena de texto que aún falta por traducir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sugerencia de traducción:

> Esta respuesta ha estado en el sitio durante bastante tiempo, es
>   probable que no se beneficie de los comentarios. Si crees que podría
>   arreglarse, vuelve y deja un comentario explicando el problema.

Comment: Sugiero: "*La respuesta ha estado en el sitio durante bastante tiempo, probablemente no se beneficiará de los comentarios. Si crees que podría arreglarse, cancela y deja un comentario explicando el problema.*"

Comment: ¡Siempre hay alguna cosa pendiente de traducir! :) Sugiero añadirlo como respuesta a la pregunta que hay para este efecto.